# How to replace parameter of a json file by a shell script?

Tags: json, bash, jq

Let's say 123.json with below content:

```
{
  "LINE" : {
    "A_serial" : "1234",
    "B_serial" : "2345",
    "C_serial" : "3456",
    "X_serial" : "76"
  }
}
```

If I want to use a shell script to change the parameter of `X_serial` by the original number +1 which is 77 in this example.
I have tried the below script to take out the parameter of `X_serial`:

```
grep "X_serial" 123.json | awk {print"$3"}
```

which outputs `76`. But then I don't know how to make it into 77 and then put it back to the parameter of `X_serial`.

Comment: Cross posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/590365

Comment: Why are the numbers strings and not integers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use line-oriented tools for parsing/manipulating JSON data. Use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) instead, for example:

```
$ jq '.LINE.X_serial |= "\(tonumber + 1)"' 123.json
{
  "LINE": {
    "A_serial": "1234",
    "B_serial": "2345",
    "C_serial": "3456",
    "X_serial": "77"
  }
}
```

This simply updates `.LINE.X_serial` by converting its value to a number, increasing the result by one, and converting it back to a string.

Comment: If I don't have the tool jq processor, what other command can i use?

Comment: @Owen No idea, python maybe.

Comment: `jq` can be downloaded as standalone tool

Comment: For anyone else reading this: If the `json` data is coming from another source, you can pipe it to `jq` and eventually output it to a different file. Just don't forget the leading `.` char.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install powerful JSON querying processor like jq processor. you can can easily install from [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

once you install jq processor, try following command to extract the variable from JSON key value

```
value=($(jq -r '.X_serial' yourJsonFile.json))
```

you can modify the `$value` as you preferred operations

Answer (score 1):

With pure Javascript: [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) and [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```js
node <<EOF
var o=$(</tmp/file);
o["LINE"]["X_serial"] = parseInt(o["LINE"]["X_serial"]) + 1;
console.log(o);
EOF
```

### Output

```
{ LINE:
   { A_serial: '1234',
     B_serial: '2345',
     C_serial: '3456',
     X_serial: 78 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**sed** or **perl**, depending on whether you just need string substitution or something more sophisticated, like arithmetic.

Since you tried grep and awk, let's start with sed:

In all lines that contain TEXT, replace foo with bar

```
sed -n '/TEXT/ s/foo/bar/ p'
```

So in your case, something like:

```
sed -n '/X_serial/ s/\"76\"/\"77\"/ p'
```

or

```
$ cat 123.json | sed  '/X_serial/ s/\"76\"/\"77\"/' > new.json
```

This performs a literal substiution: "76" -> "77"

If you would like to perform arithmetic, like "+1" or "+10" then use **perl** not sed:

```
$ cat 123.json | perl -pe 's/\d+/$&+10/e if /X_serial/'
{
  "LINE" : {
    "A_serial" : "1234",
    "B_serial" : "2345",
    "C_serial" : "3456",
    "X_serial" : "86"
  }
}
```

This operates on all lines containing X_serial (whether under "LINE" or under something else), as it is not a json parser.

Comment: Since the value of "X_serial" will change which means i can't use exactly "76\", Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Owen, Ok, I edited it to include arithmetic. I personally prefer using shell tools (like awk, sed, perl etc...) over jq whenever the task can be done with them. But if you need to read the json to find only X_serial under LINE, then yes you have to use jq or some other json parsing tool.